# Jquery Isotope random shuffle on window resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using jQuery Isotope on my site to load a wall of images. What I have works fine but I want to add a few extra things to it but I can't find anything on their site to do it...

When the browser window resizes I want it to suffle as it reorders the images.

Can this be done?

this is what I have so far:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

  var $container = $('#isotope-container');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-element',
    sortBy : 'random' // THIS IS NOT WORKING TO SORT
  });

  var $optionSets = $('#isotope-options .option-set'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

      $optionLinks.click(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        var options = {},
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[ key ] = value;
        if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
          // changes in layout modes need extra logic
          changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
        } else {
          // otherwise, apply new options
          $container.isotope( options );
        }

        return false;
      });

      $('.isotope-element img').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $this.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random()*1500)); 
        }, Math.floor(Math.random()*1500));
    }
);
 });

})(jQuery);
```

Any help with this will be very much appreciated.

Thanks
C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I looked into this a little more and actually tested it this time :)
Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {  
    $container.isotope( 'shuffle', function() {});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shuffle with a button click for example you can use this simpler code

```js
$('.shuffle-button').on( 'click', function() {
  $grid.isotope('shuffle');
});
```